# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_k$ converges Does this imply that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_k\sin(a_k)$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

this is a Homework I did a few days ago, my solution differs from the official solution, but the conclusion is correct. Yet I'm not sure if this is just coincidence as my solution is very simple.
I am grateful if you could have a look.

The question:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ converges
Does this imply that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_ksin(a_k)$ converges?

So I thought that because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely we have that $\lim{n\to \infty}$ of $a_k= 0$ .
 $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
Therefore I thought:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {\sin(a_k)}{a_k} = 1$$

So there is some $N$ after which $$\sin(a_k) \approx a_k$$

And $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_ka_k$ converges. 
So I break apart the Series to $$S_N = \sum_{k=0}^N b_k\sin(a_k)$$ as:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_k\sin(a_k) = S_N + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty b_ka_k$$

I think it must be wrong now. But I can't see why?
I apologize about the formatting, I'm still not very good at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong because it assumes that $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty b_ka_k=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty b_k\sin(a_k)$, which is not true.

Comment: Hi Jose, thank you! So, even though $\lim sin(a_k) = a_k $ as $k \to \infty$ there will never be a point where these two are equal?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum b_k \sin (a_k)$ is absolutely convergent because $|\sin x | \leq |x|$ and $\sum a_kb_k$ is absolutely convergent

Comment: Hi Kavi, thanks, that was actually more or less the idea of the official solution.